# AnyLogic: determine where my agent want to behave in 'Continuous, based on GIS map'

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I need to simulate a wide range business activities, including a rail network and some stations inside it. The Problem is that I need a global scope of the network using the GIS Map, and data analysis is needed in this scope. Meanwhile I need microscopic analysis of some stations to evaluate how each station rail yard is working.

To solve this I created a new agent for my rail network environment and developed a simple rail flowchart but when the first train is going to be injected from trainSource the following error is displayed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.<population>[1]:

This agent is already defined as agent living in space 'Continuous' and can't have behaviour for space 'Continuous, based on GIS map'
```

My base agent is Main where I have used a GIS map and the space is turned into GIS.
I have created a new agent RailEnvironmnet where I have created my rail network and a simple rail logic.

I have used an object of my RailEnvironmnet as railEnvironmnet  in my Main agent in order to be able to access to the defined view area in railEnvironmnet.

[image]

Also I have created a simple rail network and logic in my RailEnvironmnet, as shown below;

[image]

The train source of the above logic uses to newly defined agents as rail car and train type.

[image]

And finally I have deselect the checkbox of rail car and train type and RailEnvironmnet in my Main agent space and network settings.

[image]

but I still get the mentioned error above; This agent is already defined as agent living in space 'Continuous' and can't have behaviour for space 'Continuous, based on GIS map'. and the error is thrown when the train source is to inject a new train.

Anyone knows how can I solve this error? Or any other way to solve my main issue?